# Force Android tablet into MIDI USB mode

Tags: javascript, android, midi, web-midi

I'm using an Android (Huewei) tablet to control a digital music synthesiser over USB using HTML/Javascript on the Chrome browser with the webmidi extensions.  This works fine but I have to open the Settings panel and set the USB port to MIDI before using it each time which is slow and painful.  Is there any way to programatically either force the USB port into MIDI mode, or at least offer a window to the user to agree to set this mode ?

I've Developer options enabled so it's not that.

Comment: Interesting... I haven't needed to do this on my Pixel, nor any previous Android phone.  In fact, I don't use MIDI mode at all.  I always thought that mode meant the Android device was the MIDI device rather than the host.

Comment: Found an old Android phone and it does remember its in MIDI mode once put there.  Thus seems to be a new 'feature'.    I thought MIDI mode was for it being a device as well, but without setting the phone or tablet to MIDI mode, the ALSA library on the digital synth doesn't recognise it as a valid source of MIDI data so ignores it.

Comment: Bought a Samsung tablet and it does remember USB is in MIDI mode.  Seems to be a Huawei modification.  Moral : don't buy Huawei tablet for use as MIDI controller.